# Is it against the law to break someone's wand?

Tags: harry-potter

- Wands do break
- They are very personal; linked to and learning from their owner
- They are (somewhat) sentient and unique
- Essentially, on the surface a very nice stick

Is there any special law regarding the breaking of someone's wand or is it (as seen by the law) comparable to any other form of property damage?

Are there any occurrences of malicious wand-breaking throughout the books?

Comment: Re "occurrences of malicious wand breaking" - They broke Hagrid's wand when he got expelled, but I'm pretty sure that it was legal to do so.

Comment: @Kevin 'they' were the Ministry of Magic. Police people are allowed to do things that other people aren't.

Comment: Also, do wizards have wand insurance?

Comment: @marcello: Hence why I assumed it was legal.

Comment: During the fight at the MoM some guy breaks Neville's wand as as well as nose with a kick, I think that counts as malicious wand breaking

Comment: @kevin fair enough

Comment: I think it would be against the law but more like the usual "destruction of property" instead of a specific law designed for the wands

Comment: @Kevin But if you already assumed that it was a Ministry of Magic exception, then the comment didn't address the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two cases in the novels that we know of wands breaking.

1. When Hagrid was expelled
2. When Ron's wand was broken by the
   whomping willow.

Hagrid's wand was broken by the order of the state, so we can't tell if this is not legal. What it seems would be illegal is him buying another one as Olivander both know that he was expelled and makes sure that the wand was destroyed (it was not of course). So it does seem that wand breaking can be a form of exile from performing magic.

Ron's wand was broken maliciously but not by a person (I'm not sure if the whomping willow is sentient or not). However, we can see by the reaction of people to this that it is not that serious a matter. Harry and Ron are at the time in a lot of trouble, and the broken wand was an afterthought. If there were special circumstances around wand breaking you would think that it would be noted at this point. AS it is, it is seen as an annoyance by Ron rather than any special loss. Like a laptop or phone breaking, rather than the loss of a pet for example.

So in the absence of any contradictory evidence, I would say there is nothing special about wands breaking or being broken.

Comment: I suppose the intricacies of wandlore aren't known to most people so they may not even understand the connections they're developing. Like a phone learning a users speech pattern and adapting to them and the user just takes it for granted.

Comment: What about breaking the Elder Wand?

Comment: @SovereignSun Harry was the master of the elder wand.